# Missing bean EmbeddedWebApplicationContext when running project

Tags: java, spring-boot, webservice-client

I'm trying to access a webservice from a portlet. I'm pretty new at Spring, so I used this tutorial --> http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial.

When I try to run my project following exception is thrown: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.icredit</groupId>
    <artifactId>einvoice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>einvoice Portlet</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.10.6</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
        <spring.suite.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring.suite.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>BatchDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.BatchDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>BatchDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerAccountDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerAccountDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>CustomerAccountDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>CustomerDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.DocumentDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>DocumentDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.DocumentTemplateDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>DocumentTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailStatusDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.EmailStatusDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>EmailStatusDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.EmailTemplateDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>EmailTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>FileService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.FileService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>FileService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>SenderDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.SenderDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>SenderDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My main method that I run:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CustomerDaoConfiguration.class, new String[0]);      
        //CustomerClient custClient = ctx.getBean(CustomerClient.class);    

    }   
}
```

And My CustomerDaoConfiguration.class =

```
@Configuration
public class CustomerDaoConfiguration {



    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerDaoService");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerClient weatherClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        CustomerClient client = new CustomerClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://ws08-icreditlc.iconos.be:18080/icredit-service-data/CustomerDaoService");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

}
```

A full stack trace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.6.RELEASE)

2014-09-09 11:34:32.337  INFO 5088 --- [           main] b.i.einvoice.webserviceTest.Application  : Starting Application on W7-010545 with PID 5088 (C:\Users\staelko\git\einvoice-portlets\einvoice\target\classes started by staelko in C:\Users\staelko\git\einvoice-portlets\einvoice)
2014-09-09 11:34:32.395  INFO 5088 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4cedf389: startup date [Tue Sep 09 11:34:32 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-09-09 11:34:32.614  WARN 5088 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
    ... 7 common frames omitted

2014-09-09 11:34:32.628  INFO 5088 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/staelko/git/einvoice-portlets/einvoice/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/com/liferay/portal/portal-service/6.2.1/portal-service-6.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/com/liferay/portal/util-bridges/6.2.1/util-bridges-6.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/com/liferay/portal/util-taglib/6.2.1/util-taglib-6.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/com/liferay/portal/util-java/6.2.1/util-java-6.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/javax/portlet/portlet-api/2.0/portlet-api-2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.4/servlet-api-2.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-core/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-xml/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-xml-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/4.0.7.RELEASE/spring-oxm-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/staelko/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar]
2014-09-09 11:34:32.629 ERROR 5088 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
    ... 7 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
    ... 7 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed `spring-boot-starter-web`.

From other side you have a lot of redundant deps in your POM, which can be addressed just with boot-starters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found that if I simply used the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and started the project with `mvn spring-boot:run` the problem was solved.